# soketi exec_curl error: "OpenSSL/1.1.1u: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-native, ssl

when I try to broadcast an event through laravel, php pusher and my soketi server, I used certbot to get my SSL certificates to use on my soketi connections, however I'm getting the following error:

```
[2024-01-22 23:38:51] development.ERROR: exec_curl error: {error} {"error":"OpenSSL/1.1.1u: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure"} 
[2024-01-22 23:38:51] development.INFO: exec_curl response: {response} {"response":"Array
(
    [body] => 
    [status] => 0
)
"} 
[2024-01-22 23:38:51] development.ERROR: Pusher error: .
```

I run soketi through a supervisor daemon that is always running(notice my enviroment variables):

```
[program:soketi]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=soketi start 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=Gabotron
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/home/Gabotron/logs/soketi.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/Gabotron/logs/soketi.out.log
stopwaitsecs=60
stopsignal=sigint
minfds=10240
environment=SOKETI_SSL_CERT="/etc/letsencrypt/live/laraapp.com/fullchain.pem",SOKETI_SSL_KEY="/etc/letsencrypt/live/laraapp.com/privkey.pem",SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_ID="XXXX",SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_KEY="XXXX",SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_SECRET="XXXX", PATH="/home/Gabotron/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s",NODE_ENV="production"
```

My client connection:

```
let options = {
            key: env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
            wsHost:'laraapp.com',
            wsPort: 6001,
            wssPort: 6001,
            cluster:'eu',
            enableStats: true,
            logToConsole: true,
            encrypted: true,
            forceTLS: false,
            enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
        };

        let PusherClient = new Pusher(options.key, options);
        PusherClient.connection.bind('error', () => console.log('PusherClient::error', arguments));

        const echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            client: PusherClient,
            ...options
        });
```

My nginx larapp.com file:

```
server {
    server_name laraapp.com www.laraapp.com;


        root /var/www/laraapp.com/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/laraapp.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/laraapp.com/error.log;


    # serve static files directly
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
                access_log off;
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
        if (!-d $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        }

        # enforce NO www
        if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
        {
                set $host_without_www $1;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
        }

        # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
                break;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001; # Point to the Soketi port
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/laraapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/laraapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.laraapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = laraapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name laraapp.com www.laraapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

My broadcasting file:

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'log' => true,
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                //'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
                'port' => 443,
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME') === 'https',
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

My .env file

```
PUSHER_APP_KEY="XXXX"
PUSHER_APP_SECRET="XXXX"
PUSHER_APP_ID="XXXX"
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="eu"
SOKETI_DEBUG=1
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
```

Package versions:
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
"laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",

Please help, I have been stuck for a while